# Keyboard shortcut is not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

I am trying to use the shortcut `ctrl+1` or `ctrl+2` to switch between open tab in firefox. I am not sure why it is not working. Is there any way to make it work, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 47.0. Ctrl + #Number does not work. However, Meta (ALT) + #number works fine.
Try with:

Alt+1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

Select Tab 1 to 8  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>8</kbd>
Select Last Tab     <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>
New Tab               <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

<sub>**Source:** [Firefox Help | Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts#w_navigation)</sub>